# Is it possible to achieve receive eth and mint nft in the same contract?

Tags: contract-development, erc-721, nft, payable

Recently I'm build some `ERC721` nft contract.

I know that smart contract can receive `ETH`, so my question is that is it possible to write a payable function, and upon receive some ETH from someone, the contract will **mint** an NFT right away and send to the msg sender?

If not, what will be the recommended way to buy an `NFT` with ETH instead of going through some third party platform like **OpenSea**?

Thanks!

Comment: Yes, everybody is doing it this way -- unless you need random minting which is a little more complicated

Comment: @WilliamEntriken Hi! thanks for the reply. Do you have some examples of this kind of contract? like those written by openzeppelin. Because I can't seem to find an open-source template..

Comment: Yes, here is an example contract which accepts direct Ether payment and vends an ERC-721 token. It is linked from the ERC-721 standard as a demo and it was recently re-released os open source: https://github.com/su-squares/ethereum-contract/blob/master/contracts/SuVending.sol

Answer (score 1):

yes indeed. Here's a small example of how we do it:

```
function mint(uint _parentTokenIndex) public payable 
{
    require(msg.value >= NFT_PRICE, "Not enough ETH sent.");
    require(!_assetExists[_parentTokenIndex], "The asset does not meet the unique constraint.");

    _mint(msg.sender, _id);
    _setTokenURI(_id, METADATA_URL);
    _assetExists[_parentTokenIndex] = true;
}
```

Steps are like this:

- Make your function payable.
- Add a requirement for sent eth: `require(msg.value >= NFT_PRICE, "Not enough ETH sent.");`.
- Mint your NFT.